# shell script copy from one file and paste on another file

Tags: xml, shell, sh

I want to copy some lines from one file and paste it to another file at a particular 
location using shell script

For example: I want to copy lines with string `"name2"` and `"inst"` in the line and ending with line `</inst>` after the string `name2` from `file1.xml` to `file2.xml`.

The location to paste the lines in file2.xml is the before the line containing text "clipKTP".

`file1.xml`

```
    <Manufacturer clause >
        <inst abtz "nameABC">  //Inst nameABC
            <pressure 100> </pressure>
            <temp 50> </temp>
        </inst>
        <inst abtz "name2">  //Inst name2
            <pressure 100> </pressure>
            <temp 50> </temp>
        </inst>
        <inst abtz "name5678">  //Inst name5678
            <pressure 100> </pressure>
            <temp 50> </temp>
        </inst>
    </Manufacturer>
```

`file2.xml`

```
    <Measure> atk
        <inst abtz "name1">  // Inst name1
            <pressure 100></pressure>
            <temp 50></temp>
        </inst>
        <clipton> "clipKTP"
            <slave slvgo > </slave>
        </clipton>
    </Measure>
```

Result `file2.xml` should look like

```
    <Measure> atk
        <inst abtz "name1">  // Inst name1
            <pressure 100></pressure>
            <temp 50></temp>
        </inst>
        <inst abtz "name2">  //Inst name2
            <pressure 100></pressure>
            <temp 50></temp>
        </inst>
        <clipton "clipKTP">
            <slave slvgo > </slave>
        </clipton>
    </Measure>
```

Comment: what did you do so far ?

Comment: can you do this in an editor?   is the reason you need to do this in the shell since you will do it repeatedly?  if so, what are the circumstances?   i can think of an awk script, but need more information to help.

Comment: my first thought would be to use a proper XML parser, but sadly you have invalid xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the interesting part easily with `sed` or `awk`  and insert it at its right place with `sed` or `awk`.

```
 excerpt=$(sed -n -e '/name2/,/<\/inst>/p' file1.xml)
 awk -v excerpt="$excerpt" '
   printed == 0 && /clipton/ {
     print(excerpt);
     print($0); printed = 1
 }' < file2.xml > file2-result.xml
```